# table doesn't exist in another account in dompdf in localhost

Tags: php, session, dompdf

when i login my account in localhost and when I click the link to generate a pdf file it works perfectly with table and SQL data. but when I login another account the table doesn't exit.

This is one of my example of my codes:

```
$query = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM grade WHERE SEM = 1 AND YR = 1 AND  STUDENT_NUMBER = '".$_SESSION["usersnum"]."' AND LAST_NAME = '".$_SESSION["lastname"]."' AND FIRST_NAME = '".$_SESSION["firstname"]."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
         {

$html .='<table>
    <tr>
        echo "<td>'.$row["SUBJ_CODE"].'</td>"
        echo "<td colspan = "3">'.$row["SUBJ_DESC"].'</td>"
        echo "<td>'.$row["GRADE"].'</td>"
        echo "<td>'.$row["UNIT"].'</td>"
        
    </tr>
    </table>';
```

[Screenshot of table doesn't exist in another account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3fqO.png)

[the Second image have table exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5t78.png)

- I think the CSS style do not read when I login in another account in localhost.

  ```
  $html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <style>
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
    td, th{
        border: 1px solid;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .total{
        text-align: right;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            echo "<th>Name: '.$_SESSION["lastname"].' '.$_SESSION["firstname"].' '.$_SESSION["middlename"].'</th>"
            echo "<th>Course: '.$_SESSION["course"].' '.$_SESSION["cyear"].' '.$_SESSION["section"].'</th>"
            echo "<th>Student number:  '.$_SESSION["usersnum"].'</th>"
        </tr>
        </table>';
    }}
  ```

the code above is the one do not read when I login into another which the CSS style are inlucded.

Comment: First check: make sure <?php session_start(); ?> is placed at the **top** of the scripts.

Comment: @KenLee yes i included that.

Comment: @KenLee is there any way to fix this? I'm stuck with this dilemma.